# js validation with validator.addMethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to validate a drop down box. It should show a validation message if the value in the dropdown box is null. I am in a situation of not removing null value from default option.I have the following options for dropdown list.

' '(null value by default)

option1

option2

option3

I am using regular expression to pass null value.

http://jsfiddle.net/fY2xm/

```
 I don't know is that correct passing null value. or any other way.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given case you need to use required validation because since the `regexp` rule is testing for `optional` condition it will always return true since the value is empty for the null option.

```
$("#formname").validate({
    debug: true, //prevent submission for testing
    rules: {
        textbox: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Je4BJ/)

Comment: hey it's not working. It consider null as a value. I tried it initially but no use.

Answer (score 1):

From your fiddle, your not passing values.

```
<select name='select'> <!--Don't forget to give name-->
        <option value=''></option>
        <option value='1'>Australia</option>
        <option value='2'>England</option>
        <option value='3'>United States</option>
    </select>
```

Then JS:

```
$("#formname").validate({
    debug: true, //prevent submission for testing
    rules: {
        'select': {
            required: true ---------------------
        }                                      |
    },                                         |
    messages: {                                |
        'select': {                            |
            required: "Select a country"--------
        }
    }
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fY2xm/9/)

Comment: @Jeff Though late, glad to help you